Using Generic Type in Extension method
I am writing a generic extension method e.g. AddCors() in my .net aspire project ServiceDefaults to avoid re-writing for each service. However, properties may differ from service to service. Below is my code so far:
public static class CorsExtensions
{
    /**
     * appsettings.json configuration
     * 
     * CorsPolicy:{
     *      "PolicyName": "",
     *      "AllowedHosts": "*",
     *      "AllowedOrigins": "http://localhost:4200",
     *      "AllowedHeaders": "content-type",
     *      "AllowedMethods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE"
     * }
     */
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureCors<T>(this IServiceCollection services) where T: class
    {
        var configuration = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();
        var corsPolicy = services.Configure<T>(configuration!.GetSection("CorsPolicy"));
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: corsPolicy.PolicyName,
                policy => policy.WithOrigins(corsPolicy.AllowedOrigins)
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .WithHeaders(corsPolicy.AllowedHeaders)
                    .WithMethods(corsPolicy.AllowedMethods)
                    );
        });
        return services;
    }

    public static WebApplication AddCorsMiddleware<T>(this WebApplication app)
    {
        app.UseCors(T.PolicyName);
        return app;
    }
}

and in Service A, I am trying to consume as below:
builder.Services.ConfigureCors<CorsPolicy>();

public class CorsPolicy
{
    public string PolicyName { get; set; } 
    public string AllowedHosts { get; set; }
    public string AllowedMethods { get; set; }
    public string AllowedHeaders { get; set; }
    public string AllowedOrigins { get; set; }
}

As mentioned, properties may differ from service to service, Model is being declared in service projects.
How can I write the extension method to dynamically read the properties and configure accordingly.

I suspect you'll need T to implement an interface which exposes the PolicyName and a method to configure the policy.

Hint: What would you expect to happen if you called AddCorsMiddleware<Stream>? Also note that CorsPolicy.PolicyName is an instance property - which instance do you expect AddCorsMiddleware to take that property from?

@JonSkeet it is based on the service calling AddCorsMiddleware as the name will be changed per service to distinguish among the policy names.

I don't see how that answers either of my questions. You appear to be trying to access a static property on an unconstrained generic type in AddCorsMiddleware by accessing T.PolicyName. It's really unclear how you'd expect that to work. (You almost certainly at least want to declare an interface with a property, so that you can constrain T to that interface; you also potentially want to keep it as an instance property and do something (whether using a parameter or not) to provide an instance of the policy to the method.)

@JonSkeet can you provide an example. As per my understanding, the value should be populated from appsettings.json file when ConfigureCors is called in services pipeline.

@RichardDeeming can you provide an example?

@AssadNazar: Not with the current code, no. The problems I've identified are all in AddCorsMiddleware, and you haven't shown how or where you expect to call that. It's unclear whether your question is primarily about that method or ConfigureCors, or how those methods relate to each other. But most importantly, it's not clear that you understand the problems I've already pointed out with AddCorsMiddleware.

@JonSkeet what i want to achieve is create extensions in ServiceDefaults project which is already referenced in all of my services. Each service has it's own CORS Policy. Policy name will differentiate policies against each service. These extensions will then be added to services and app pipelines.

It's still unclear whether you've actually taken on board and understood any of the problems I've identified. I'm afraid I don't have any more time to spend on this.

You can't do T.PolicyName. T is a type, not an object.
If I understood the question properly, you can create an interface and have each policy to implement it, then you can type-match the interface with corresponding class:
public class MyPolicy: ICorsPolicy
{
    public string PolicyName { get; set; } 
    public string AllowedHosts { get; set; }
    public string AllowedMethods { get; set; }
    public string AllowedHeaders { get; set; }
    public string AllowedOrigins { get; set; }
}

public interface ICorsPolicy {
   public string PolicyName { get; set; }
   ...
}

...
public static WebApplication AddCorsMiddleware(this WebApplication app, ICorsPolicy policy)
{
    if (policy is CorsPolicy corsPolicy) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    return app;
}

Same in ConfigureCors.
Of course you can also do a factory and construct the objects accordingly.
